# Removing elements from <ul> on <li> click

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
    <ul id="images">
        @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
        {
            <li id="@image.Id" style="list-style-type: none;">
                <img src="@image.Path?width=200"/><br/>
                <span id="remove"><i class="icon-minus"></i> <a href="#">Remove</a></span>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

I have this code , that shows pictures, What i want is allow user to remove some, if user want.

I m not sure how to attack to it.

First of all, how can i find out which li item was clicked and how I can remove it from list.

Then I need to invoke a Ajax post to a handler/controller to actually remove it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#images li').click(function(){
        var liId = this.id;
        $(this).remove();
        //call ajax here
    });
 });
```

If li are added dynamically, you have to use delegation:

```
$(function(){
        $('#images').on('click','li',function(){
            $(this).remove();
            //call ajax here
        });
     });
```

Comment: how do i get the `li` id? so i can invoke ajax?

Comment: just use this.id to get li id inside click callback function scope

Comment: @Joel no need to use jquery for getting elem id, this.id works and is more suitable (doesn't wrap DOM object inside a jquery object)